# How to add a function definition available in a string to a class generated from kotlinpoet TypeSpec?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinpoet

I am generating a class using kotlinpoet and one of the method to be generated is available to me as string (full function definition), how will I add that to a TypeSpec?

```
// if I have function definition like this
val funDefinition = "fun myFun(){}"

// I don't want to generate like following
TypeSpec.classBuilder("myClass").addFunction(FunSpec.builder("myFun").build())

// I could not see an option like following
TypeSpec.classBuilder("myClass").aMethodToAddFunctionFromString(funDefinition)
```

Is this possible with kotlinpoet or with some other library?

Comment: It's not possible to do this with KotlinPoet. You'll likely need to write your own parser to extract the function name and other necessary data from your input string.

Comment: FunSpec.addCode() helped after extracting the function definition